# Multiprocessing using csv+pandas+python

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have written a code that would iterate over each csv in a folder, read it using data-frame and append it to a master df which would be later user.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


constituent_df= pd.DataFrame()

def process(file):
    '''
    This Function reads csv and appends it to a global data-frame
    Parameters:
        file-> csv file
    '''
    fields= ('REGION', 'CURR')
    print("Pandas Reading:", file)
    csv_df= pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

    constituent_df= constituent_df.append(csv_df, ignore_index=True)

def main():
    '''
    This module reads files present in the directory
    And 
    '''
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    start= time.time()
    constituent_df= pd.DataFrame()
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'2653AM\\*.csv')):
        pool.apply_async(process,[file])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()   
    end= time.time()
    print("It took:", end-start)

    print(constituent_df)
    constituent_df.to_excel(excel_writer="Constituent_Data_MP.xlsx", index=False)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
    #print(constituent_df)
```

I am not able to save constituent_df. Can anyone guide me on how to store constituent_df? Is there any other way?

Comment: Instead of doing the multiprocessing etc... yourself, you might want to consider taking advantage of [`dask`](https://dask.org/)

Comment: It's the similar question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368682/python-multiprocessing-a-large-dataframe-on-linux/58369800#58369800

Answer (score 0):

I modified the way i wanted to process files in pool and got a working solution:

```
def main():
    '''
    This module reads files present in the directory
    And 
    '''
    file_list=[]
    constituent_df= pd.DataFrame()

    start= time.time()

    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'2653AM\\*.csv')):
        file_list.append(file)

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        df_list = pool.map(process_csv, file_list)
        constituent_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
    end= time.time()
    print("It took:", end-start)
```